# How to forward external audio streams to a Virtual Audio Cable?

Tags: c++, windows, audio

I've been trying to figure out how to send audio streams from recording devices and playback devices to a Virtual Audio Cable in C++. I've seen some applications do it, however they weren't open source so I wasn't able to see how they did it.

Maybe someone could put me on the right track?

Answer (score 0):

> [It creates a set of](http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm) virtual audio devices named "Virtual Cables", each of them consists of a pair of the waveform input/output devices. Any application can send audio stream to an output side of a cable, and any other application can receive this stream from an input side. All transfers are made digitally, providing NO sound quality loss (a bitperfect streaming).

One application receives external audio feed and uses standard audio API to play the stream back to virtual audio device.

Then this audio feed is available for others applications via standard audio capture APIs, from VAC's counterpart virtual device.

That is, "forward" in your question is essentially a standard playback of this stream.

Comment: Thank you for answering, unfortunately I am easily confused and don't understand that well what you mean. I am not using the application Virtual Audio Cable driver, I meant any Virtual Audio Device that functions as a recording device. Sorry if I misunderstood you.

Comment: Well... "Virtual Audio Cable" is specific popular driver that implements virtual device which can be used by audio-aware applications. There is no other virtual audio cable device, esp. generic one. "Virtual" assumes that there is specific software which backs this virtuality and implements a device which does not exist physically. Perhaps you should update your question to clarify what you are really looking for.